# How to select closest attribute with custom attribute name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Please see my below html code.

```
<tr> .....</tr>

<tr>
        <td data-colname="ctv">hello</td>
        <td class="my_t">Yes</td>
        <td class="mybutton">Click here</td>
        </tr>

<tr> .....</tr>
```

I can select my_t value in my custom function using

```
$(".mybutton").on("click",function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").find(".my_t").css("color","red");
});
```

**it is working fine.**

But  ***below code is not working***. how I can select **data-colname="ctv**" **in   ?

```
$(".mybutton").on("click",function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("[data-colname='ctv']").css("color","green");
    });
```

Please help

**EDIT**  Added a snippet with the above code

```js
$(".mybutton").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".my_t").css("color", "red");
});
$(".mybutton").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("[data-colname='ctv']").css("color", "green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-colname="ctv">hello</td>
    <td class="my_t">Yes</td>
    <td class="mybutton">Click here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is x? because from this code `X.closest("[data-colname='ctv']");` X should be a child,

Comment: Hi  Please don't bother about px . my question is closest(".my_t") is working but how can i  select closest("[data-colname='ctv']")

Comment: `closest` seeks along **the parent hierarchy of the given element**. You may go to the immediate parent and then search in it's children elements.

Comment: Where is your starting point?  In the *provided* html, the only thing that would find `my_t` with `.closest(".my_t")` would be the text "Yes".  Assuming there's actually a button or something to click in there and not just text, what's the equivalent to find the other `td`?   Are you starting at the same point (text "Yes")?  If so:  `.closest(".my_t").prev()`

Comment: *select data-colname="ctv" in closest tr* would be `x.closest("tr").find("[data-colname]")`

Comment: Thanks for the update with the `.closest("tr")` - your code now works completely fine *as provided*.  You really need to create a snippet in your question, add your code and then see if it works/doesn't work.  As it is, it works fine:   https://jsfiddle.net/jkxn9pyw/1/

Comment: I've added a snippet to the question to get you started, using your html and js.  It works fine.   What's the difference between your code (where it's not working) and the code in the question?   Can you reproduce your issue in the snippet I've provided?

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for providing this . Its working fine.

Comment: Well, got you where you needed to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, no selection works with the code you provided as it is not enclosed in a `<table>` element. Please try this :

```js
var res = $(".my_t").parent().find("[data-colname='ctv']");
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tr> .....</tr>

<tr>
  <td data-colname="ctv">hello</td>
  <td class="my_t">Yes</td>
</tr>

<tr> .....</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OPs code works fine with `.closest("tr")` - changing to `.parent()` won't work for OP as they're working from a `button` inside `td`

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that should work with this HTML structure:

```
$(".mybutton").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td[data-colname='ctv']")[0].css("color","green");
});
```

Comment: `$(...).parents(...).find(...)[0].css is not a function`.   `[0]` will give the DOM node which doesn't have the jquery css function.